# Copy n Bits from 8-bit Array into 64-bit Integer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am trying to copy n bits from any position of an array of uint8_ts into a single 64 bit integer. Here is a working solution that can copy an arbitrary amount of bits into a 64 bit integer starting at the beginning of the array, but I want to be able to start at any position of the array.

For example I might want to copy bits 2 through 11 of the array:
{7, 128, 7}

In binary that would be:
00000111 1000000 00000111

And I want an integer with value:
0001111000

```
std::uint64_t key_reg(std::uint8_t* bytes, std::size_t n)
{
  std::uint64_t reg = 0;
  // The amount of bits that fit into an entire element of an array
  // ex, if I'm copying 17 bits, even_bytes == 2
  std::size_t even_bytes = (n - (n % 8)) / 8;
  // what's left over after the even bytes
  // in this case, remainder == 1
  std::size_t remainder = n - even_bytes * 8;

  // copy each byte into the integer
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < even_bytes; ++i)
    if(remainder)
      reg |= (std::uint64_t)bytes[i] << (8 * (even_bytes - i));
    else
      reg |= (std::uint64_t)bytes[i] << (8 * (even_bytes - i - 1));

  // if there is an uneven number of bits, copy them in
  if(remainder) 
    reg |= (std::uint64_t)bytes[even_bytes];

  return reg;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to implement

```
std::uint64_t key_reg(std::uint8_t* bytes, std::size_t pos, std::size_t n);
```

I didn't think anyone would answer so fast, so here was a solution I came up with in the same style. I found this bitfieldmask function on stackoverflow, but I'm unable to find the question to credit the author.

```
template<typename R>
static constexpr R bitfieldmask(unsigned int const a, unsigned int const b)
{
  return ((static_cast<R>(-1) >> (((sizeof(R) * CHAR_BIT) - 1) - (b)))
      & ~((1 << (a)) - 1));  
}

std::uint64_t key_reg(std::uint8_t* bytes, std::size_t pos, std::size_t n)
{
  std::uint64_t reg = 0;
  std::size_t starting_byte = (pos < 8) ? 0 : ((pos - (pos % 8)) / 8);
  std::size_t even_bytes = (n - (n % 8)) / 8;
  std::size_t remainder = n - even_bytes * 8;

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < even_bytes; ++i)
    if(remainder)
      reg |= (std::uint64_t)bytes[starting_byte + i] << (8 * (even_bytes - i));
    else
      reg |= (std::uint64_t)bytes[starting_byte + i] << (8 * (even_bytes - i - 1));

  if(remainder) 
    reg |= (std::uint64_t)bytes[even_bytes];

  // mask out anything before the first bit
  if(pos % 8 != 0) {
    std::size_t a = n - pos;
    std::size_t b = n;
    auto mask = bitfieldmask<std::uint64_t>(a, b);

    reg = (reg & ~mask);
  }

  return reg;
}
```

Comment: `std::bitset` ?

Comment: Have you considered using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)? It has [`std::bitset::to_ullong()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong) to convert bits to an `unsigned long long` (an unsigned integer type with at least 64 bits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic approach looks sound.  To handle bit offsets that aren't multiples of 8, you just need to first read in a single partial byte and then proceed with the rest:

```c
uint64_t key_reg(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t pos, size_t n) {
    const uint8_t* ptr = bytes + pos / 8;
    uint64_t result = 0;

    if (pos % 8 > 0) {
        /* read the first partial byte, masking off unwanted bits */
        result = *(ptr++) & (0xFF >> (pos % 8));

        if (n <= 8 - pos % 8) {
            /* we need no more bits; shift off any excess and return early */
            return result >> (8 - pos % 8 - n);
        } else {
            /* reduce the requested bit count by the number we got from this byte */
            n -= 8 - pos % 8;
        }
    }

    /* read and shift in as many whole bytes as we need */
    while (n >= 8) {
        result = (result << 8) + *(ptr++);
        n -= 8;
    }

    /* finally read and shift in the last partial byte */
    if (n > 0) {
        result = (result << n) + (*ptr >> (8-n));
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Here's an online demo](https://tio.run/##lZVNj5swEIbv/IpRq60ggSwBNk1KkuNee2yltloRMIm1YKhtmqTV/vXSsTHka/dQDqORPfY8fmdsUm@bpu17ytKiyQgsKZPyWBMx2a2t06iQGa1wqG1wfhY9SXgmxydOtnZaMSFBDc@f5Ag2R0mEC4L@JhhUVyefOfDHAvyuVtSSw6pbB2O1Au5hHuvIIRknoikkhvmxpWdoDrYKvYM5rMHvt1bf/QjDkwzkjkBOOaaqEy5pUugcLpSJeKZsC1WeQ8P2CZMkgw2VAkb3wyZDwpGNfOOxAx/A9g@Pj7BeD5kdx9D0RAyWKwTyoA84wzJoewKMYEJWQVlxohPHIHY0l5ooYUcgh5QIgW6GHLLhDEjCi@M5X8eo5wyq4jpLjR5z4iH@BUghyC0OJ1mTEq0VJz8bIowYWKSGSVRMT7Gm3BCu2LeVhJxXJQ5ToQW9pmLgXWhwxmB11jqvkjpkd3rKIBFYHRRgv6sKYloCx3rNTKb9juIsir1eXUo8FM023nKpAsZDEU8sHWV8RZRTlhQo9C2ZUqFIrnqpB@pKf9WGr8EwBWOPVMfrcnnMcXqGm4rG1kt7cVVg0@TffuCOXRL/EE5dtJG2Dwtlg5n2Q23nyi4@ahu6Zk2g5@aRsrNAW@2H3bi2QbfmwXqJtSxlWbpQ08lkok5sIQ2WCUWxf1U068@McVguCdNPnXw@yAqmD8DoZlOoOuYSWwivXl3r28eImepVzCsOttq7IEzfdO0sYRZ13ngF0bnANcfg3H7nH@6Kr9/ZO3d4klAnF/BUuOqk7wVkYCBnkekyIVVdkSuRA3FgTnDNpxpbNY92Oj7l/Seffhpn0RuAoQEUyFR0r8QFo7qiWuEweIPP7/nCQHvqDbuFQzR4lWx62Zl9PJ7DUY35N82LZCta7wtemNbD38MqXSxaryYZPqg0bb3PwT8) with a simple test harness, demonstrating that this code indeed works correctly in all the edge cases I could find, such as reading a full 64 bits starting from the middle of a byte or reading only part of a single byte (which is actually a non-trivial special case, handled in a separate branch with its own `return` statement in the code above).

(Note that I wrote the code above in plain C since, like your original code, it doesn't really make use of any C++ specific features.  Feel free to "C++ify" it by adding `std::` where appropriate.)

One feature that the test harness doesn't check, but which I believe this code should possess, is that it never reads more bytes from the input array than necessary.  In particular, the `bytes` array is not accessed at all if `n == 0` (although a pointer to `pos / 8` bytes after the start of the array is still calculated).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just simpler to copy all necessary bytes and then mask extra bits:

```
std::uint64_t key_reg(std::uint8_t* bytes, std::size_t n)
{
   std::uint64_t reg = 0;
   std::reverse_copy( bytes, bytes + n / 8 + ( n % 8 != 0 ), 
                      reinterpret_cast<char *>( &reg ) );
   reg >>= n % 8;
   reg &= ~( -1UL << n );
   return reg;
}
```

using `pos` would be little more complex:

```
std::uint64_t key_reg(std::uint8_t* bytes, std::size_t pos, std::size_t n)
{
   std::uint64_t reg = 0;
   auto endpos = pos + n;
   auto start = bytes + pos / 8;
   auto end = bytes + endpos / 8 + ( endpos % 8 != 0 );
   std::reverse_copy( start,  end, reinterpret_cast<char *>( &reg ) );
   reg >>= endpos % 8;
   reg &= ~( -1UL << n );
   return reg;
}
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/MTodU3)

Comment: I tested this on the array {255, 0, 255} from position 2, with 15 bits, and got the value 111111 rather than 1111110000000

Comment: I probably messed with endianness, let me fix that

Comment: @SamG fixed, it was not simple to deduct order of bytes from your code

Comment: Though you need to do more testing, if you provide some test data I can add it to ideone

Answer (score 0):

I have the following

```
struct MyType
{
std::array<uint8_t, 892> m_rguID;
    uint16_t m_bitLength;


void GetBits(uint16_t startBit, uint16_t nBits, uint64_t & bits) const
};


void MyType::GetBits(uint16_t startBit, uint16_t nBits, uint64_t & bits) const
{
    if(startBit + nBits > m_bitLength)
        throw std::runtime_error("Index is out of range");
    uint32_t num1 = startBit % 8U;
    uint32_t num2 = 8U - num1;
    uint32_t num3 = nBits >= num2 ? num2 : nBits;
    uint32_t num4 = startBit >> 3;
    bits = (uint64_t)(((int64_t)((uint64_t)m_rguID[num4] >> (8 - num3 - num1)) & (int64_t)((1 << num3) - 1)) << (nBits - num3));
    uint32_t num5 = num4 + 1U;
    int num6 = nBits - num3;
    if(num6 <= 0)
        return;
    int num7 = num6 - 8;
    int num8 = 8 - num6;
    do
    {
        if(num6 >= 8)
        {
            bits |= (uint64_t)m_rguID[num5] << num7;
            ++num5;
        }
        else
        {
            bits |= (uint64_t)m_rguID[num5] >> num8;
            ++num5;
        }
        num6 += -8;
        num7 += -8;
        num8 += 8;
    } while(num6 > 0);
}
```